# PHP create core code to spread between different projects

Tags: php, git

I'm building a relatively large project which involved few servers running php.

All the servers have few shared classes they need to use.

When design the git and the project structure, it seams logical to me to write the core (shared) classes, and then wrap them up somehow (maybe Composer?) and let anyone of the specific server just the have them as dispense.

I've read some very bad reviews about git submodules, so I was wonder what alternative do I have ?

I'm trying to achieve a basic core part of the code that will be a dispense for each of the servers.

Comment: Sure, composer would be a good solution. With composer, you don't have to use git submodules.

Comment: but do I need to have it as 2 completely different projects ?

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to keep one structure and just extract the core as a composer package. Haven't tried myself. Maybe there is a possibility to use 2 separate git repositories with different .gitignore...
I would go with two separate projects.

Comment: submodules should do the trick, but its very unrecommended from different articles I read

Comment: I think it's not that big difference whether you use submodule or separate git project in the sense of code structure. So, if submodule is not good, split the project in two.

Comment: This question belongs either to "Software Recommendations" or "Superuser" i.m.o. because it does not directly involve programing. Besides of that, yes, seperating the "library" and the "application" makes sense.

Comment: @DanFromGermany it makes sense but I can't find the right or most effective way to do it..

Answer (score 2):

Ok after doing some further research I decided to go with `git subtree` feature.
I allows me to divid my code into modules inject remote modules as part of my code.

Like everything in git, there's a learning curve, but in this case it seems like it total worth it.

I used those 2 blog posts as tutorial:

https://medium.com/@v/git-subtrees-a-tutorial-6ff568381844

https://www.atlassian.com/git/articles/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/